# Getting exception while sending soap request from springboot: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?;

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, marshalling

I am getting an exception while sending soap request to third party application, and in the code nowhere i m setting the content type for Soap request.

I tried to print the soap request before marshalSendAndReceive(..) but i cannot see any request getting printed, i assume the error occurs before it could print/log the request.

Need Help!!

Below is the exception:

```
.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap   : SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. 
Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
2020-01-22 09:09:42.116 ERROR [cheque- 
service,ca93accf0bdaa764,85d910ae8dabce62,false] 230 --- [0.0-8888-exec-2] 
c.d.i.m.p.c.e.ExceptionLoggerAspect      : Cheque Print service - Unexpected 
error occurred:
org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:216)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:611)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)
at com.deloitte.insurcloud.microservices.payment.chequeservice.service.client.GwApiClient.callGuidewire(GwApiClient.java:43)
at com.deloitte.insurcloud.microservices.payment.chequeservice.service.client.GwApiClient.updateCheckStatus(GwApiClient.java:36)
at com.deloitte.insurcloud.microservices.payment.chequeservice.service.client.GwApiClient$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9966cc9c.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:84)
at com.deloitte.insurcloud.microservices.payment.chequeservice.exception.ExceptionLoggerAspect.aroundProcessException(ExceptionLoggerAspect.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **Content-Type** value is wrong.

Please use following example:

```
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
```

Note: text/xml is the SOAP 1.1 content type.